# Close a highly upvoted question?

Tags: support

OK, so the [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on) has collected a close vote (as it showed up in the close vote queue), so someone else feels like me but actually cast a close vote.

I have mixed feelings about this: **Yes, it *is* off-topic**, but it is also highly up-voted, serves a purpose (Linux is not for everyone *yet*), and has a few excellent answers.

Me, personally, would rather close all "I want Windows back" questions then cast a duplicate vote to this one, but I also don't want to be a jerk and cast an additional close vote...

#### Oli? FossFreedom? Seth? Mitch?

Any balanced answer?

Comment: The community decided it is not off-topic (it is related to Ubuntu) so it isn't off-topic. Simple as that. Do we really want to go over this again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[We've *just* been over this](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/14272/449). Popular decision: **It isn't off-topic**. Taken from my answer on this:

> I don't believe [that question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on) is a good example of a question that isn't about Ubuntu. Ubuntu is currently installed, the longhand way of reading the question could be: **What do I need to do to Ubuntu to get rid of Ubuntu and prepare for the reinstallation of Windows?**
>
> And that might very logically have plenty of Ubuntu-related things in its answer. You might need to unmount the firewire matrix from /proc/, or defragment the boot partition, or patch the 802.11 antenna array for parity switching. **The person asking doesn't know.** That's why they're asking. In short, that the answer doesn't neccessarily need to be Ubuntu related, doesn't mean the question isn't on-topic, even if only tangentially.

Yes, there are also popularity, "what makes us better" and dupe-target arguments that I might weigh for a more contentious topic, but I feel this question is entirely within our scope.

You clearly don't. And that's okay too.

Comment: I'm getting old: I don't even remember posting that!  Thanks for your patience...

Comment: Happens to the best of us ;)