# Are questions on removing Ubuntu and getting Windows back on on-topic or not?

Tags: discussion, duplicates, vote-to-close, scope

I have noticed many questions from new users asking about how to remove Ubuntu and get Window back on, half of these are getting closed as a duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on), and the rest as off-topic, but this doesn't make sense because the question that some of them are being closed as duplicates of has not been closed as off-topic, therefore should we be closing some of them as off-topic instead?

And I think that this sends a rather confusing method, are these questions off-topic or not? It it right to close them as off-topic, or should we instead be closing these questions as duplicates?

Comment: "should we be closing some of them as off-topic instead?" No, we shouldn't. "should we instead be closing these questions as duplicates?" Yes, we should

Comment: @kos: *“We need to go deeper!”* My question is directly cited as the source of the fundamental argument in the only answer to your question.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I know, but [Close a highly upvoted question?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14481/close-a-highly-upvoted-question) answers this question specifically, while [Get rid of Windows answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14271/get-rid-of-windows-answers) is more broad. I thought it was more appropriate to close in favor of the better fitting one (not that it matters too much though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have noticed many questions from new users asking about how to remove Ubuntu and get Window back on

You install Windows by using a Windows installation method. And there is ends for us.

- How you burn Windows to a DVD using Ubuntu could be on-topic but there will be a duplicate.
- Anything after that is off-topic since it will involve a possible recovery partition, bios/uefi settings, booting from the media, and installing from it. All things not related to Ubuntu and not done with Ubuntu software, tools or commands.